# CSS, HTML can't put div contents within a div tag

Tags: html, css

Hi i have questions regarding my div tags. I followed this tutorial where i specifically did exactly what he did and got different results. I have googled about this and i can not find the answer.

The problem is that my div tags inside my content_wrapper div wont place themselves within the content_wrapper div even though i specifically did the same thing as in the tutorial. Instead the div tags place themselves at the bottom over my content_wrapper div. I am currently using dreamweaver CS5 if it is any help.

This was how i wrote my divs:

```
<body>

    <div id="header"> This is my header </div>

    <div id="content_wrap"> 

        <div id="left_content"> Advertisement </div>

        <div id="right_content"> </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

This is my CSS:

```
#header{
    height:1000px;
    width:1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border:solid 1px;
}

#content_wrapper{
    height:800px;
    width:980px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    }

#left_content {
    height:800px;
    width:240px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border:solid 1px;

}

#right_content {
    height:800px;
    width:730px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:auto;
    float:right;
    border:solid 1px;
    }
```

Comment: `content_wrap` != `content_wrapper`

Comment: Check the width, height, margin, and padding on your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Your left and right divs are collapsing because you have not cleared the parent div (wrapper). add a class to your `<div id="content_wrap" class="clearfix">`

```
.clearfix:after{
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The div id "content_wrap" does not match the CSS reference "content_wrapper"

Comment: This is true, but it's not the answer to his problem. That's why I posted it as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems in addition to the ID mismatch mentioned in the comments on your question.

First, right-floated elements need to come first. Then, floated elements need to have widths that total less than the wrapper element's width, including padding and margins, or they wrap to new rows.

Finally, you probably don't want auto margins on floated elements. I can't be sure since I'm not sure what you were after.

http://jsfiddle.net/z8Gwg/

```
#header {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border:solid 1px;
}
#content_wrapper {
    height:80px;
    width:98px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
#left_content {
    height:80px;
    width:20px;
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#right_content {
    height:80px;
    width:70px;
    float:right;
    border:solid 1px;
}

<body>
    <div id="header">This is my header</div>
    <div id="content_wrapper">
        <div id="right_content"></div>
        <div id="left_content">Advertisement</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Right-floated elements do not need to come first. As long as there isn't a clear in the CSS of the floated elements.

Comment: You're right, Mike. Thanks. I was thinking of a single-float scenario, where the float needs to come before the other content.